# Multi-Lined UISegmentedControl

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

How can I make a multi lined UISegmentedControl. I need it to have 6 buttons, 3 on each line. How can I do this programatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to use two of them, using the `selectedSegmentIndex` property. If, when you get an action from one control, you set the value of the other control's property to `-1` it will effectively give you a bank of six buttons in two rows that appear to be linked together as one group.

Comment: Smart and easy way to do it. Thanks. I may just add that you can use the `[self.orderOptionsSegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(disableOtherSegmentedControl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];` to detect the selection of one of the `UISegmentedControl` I will just post the code in a new answer below hopefully someone needs it.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding code to @Adam EberBach's answer:

In `viewDidLoad`

```
[self.orderOptionsSegmentedControl1 addTarget:self action:@selector(disableOtherSegmentedControl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.orderOptionsSegmentedControl2 addTarget:self action:@selector(disableOtherSegmentedControl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Then implement the `disableOtherSegmentedControl`

```
- (void) disableOtherSegmentedControl:(id)sender
{
    if (sender == self.orderOptionsSegmentedControl1)
    {
        self.orderOptionsSegmentedControl2.selectedSegmentIndex = -1;
    }

    else if (sender == self.orderOptionsSegmentedControl2)
    {
        self.orderOptionsSegmentedControl1.selectedSegmentIndex = -1;
    }
}
```